# IntelliJ quits abruptly in the Apple M1

Tags: macos, unix, intellij-idea

I use Apple M1 and IntelIJ keeps shut down often when I login into the computer in the morning and I need to restart the app. Also, sometimes the IntelliJ just freezes and I need to force quit to start over. This is the error log that I receive:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               idea [76230]
Path:                  /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.intellij
Version:               2021.3.3 (IU-213.7172.25)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-24 11:36:30.1965 +0600
OS Version:            macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        541B5190-6726-9EDB-BC2A-7C9CE3CA560D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       202043C5-1819-45A0-B38C-FC2F621576C1

Time Awake Since Boot: 930000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4369022976
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      1046a0000-1046a8000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ts/MacOS/idea

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'java.lang.NullPointerException
java.desktop/sun.lwawt.LWWindowPeer.updateMinimumSize(LWWindowPeer.java:458)
java.desktop/sun.lwawt.LWWindowPeer.notifyReshape(LWWindowPeer.java:713)
java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.deliverMoveResizeEvent(CPlatformWindow.java:1243)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called


Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018881c1cc __exceptionPreprocess + 240
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018856d7b8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018881c018 +[NSException exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:] + 0
3   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000013fb1ef0c -[AWTWindow _deliverMoveResizeEvent] + 1104
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000188791200 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000188834b84 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000188834af0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 456
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018875feb0 _CFXNotificationPost + 720
8   Foundation                          0x0000000189615e3c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 96
9   AppKit                              0x000000018b343f40 -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:fromServer:] + 3264
10  AppKit                              0x000000018bb89cdc -[NSWindow(NSScreenLayout) _setFrame:fromAdjustmentToScreen:anchorIfNeeded:animate:] + 660
11  AppKit                              0x000000018b67717c -[NSWindow _adjustWindowToScreen] + 1292
12  AppKit                              0x000000018b69ddb8 -[NSWindow _displayChangedSoAdjustWindows:] + 116
13  AppKit                              0x000000018be3329c ___NSApplicationPerformScreenInvalidationReactions_block_invoke + 92
14  AppKit                              0x000000018b2eb188 -[NSApplication enumerateWindowsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 292
15  AppKit                              0x000000018be32d2c ___NSApplicationReactToScreenInvalidation_block_invoke + 640
16  AppKit                              0x000000018be32828 _NSApplicationReactToScreenInvalidation + 300
17  AppKit                              0x000000018be32a24 -[NSApplication(ScreenHandling) _reactToDisplayChanges:] + 408
18  AppKit                              0x000000018b9d0a40 _NSCGSDisplayConfigurationUpdateAndInvokeObservers + 456
19  AppKit                              0x000000018b9d0e04 _NSCGSDisplayConfigurationDidReconfigureNotificationHandler + 328
20  SkyLight                            0x000000018d8a8ca4 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_123notify_datagram_handlerEj15CGSDatagramTypePvmS1_ + 920
21  SkyLight                            0x000000018db99aac _ZN21CGSDatagramReadStream26dispatchMainQueueDatagramsEv + 228
22  SkyLight                            0x000000018db999a8 ___ZN21CGSDatagramReadStream15mainQueueWakeupEv_block_invoke + 28
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188510e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000188512bac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001885210ac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001887ddf00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879b8c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 2540
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
29  HIToolbox                           0x0000000191332f68 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
30  HIToolbox                           0x0000000191332cdc ReceiveNextEventCommon + 552
31  HIToolbox                           0x0000000191332a9c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
32  AppKit                              0x000000018b2f1000 _DPSNextEvent + 844
33  AppKit                              0x000000018b2ef8a4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1332
34  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000106e9bc10 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 144
35  AppKit                              0x000000018b2e19b4 -[NSApplication run] + 596
36  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000106e9b9c8 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 216
37  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000013fb76f4c +[AWTStarter starter:headless:] + 508
38  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000106e9d974 +[ThreadUtilities invokeBlockCopy:] + 28
39  Foundation                          0x0000000189690914 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 212
40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879cc5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
41  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879cba8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
42  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879c894 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
43  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879b208 __CFRunLoopRun + 820
44  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018879a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
45  idea                                0x00000001046a49c4 main + 3332
46  dyld                                0x00000001047f90f4 start + 520


Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18869d9b8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d0eb0 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18860e314 abort + 164
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18868db50 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18867ef64 demangling_terminate_handler() + 332
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x188576140 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18868cee4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18868ce80 std::terminate() + 64
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x188512bc0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1885210ac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944
10  CoreFoundation                         0x1887ddf00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
11  CoreFoundation                         0x18879b8c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 2540
12  CoreFoundation                         0x18879a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
13  HIToolbox                              0x191332f68 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
14  HIToolbox                              0x191332cdc ReceiveNextEventCommon + 552
15  HIToolbox                              0x191332a9c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
16  AppKit                                 0x18b2f1000 _DPSNextEvent + 844
17  AppKit                                 0x18b2ef8a4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1332
18  libosxapp.dylib                        0x106e9bc10 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 144
19  AppKit                                 0x18b2e19b4 -[NSApplication run] + 596
20  libosxapp.dylib                        0x106e9b9c8 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 216
21  libawt_lwawt.dylib                     0x13fb76f4c +[AWTStarter starter:headless:] + 508
22  libosxapp.dylib                        0x106e9d974 +[ThreadUtilities invokeBlockCopy:] + 28
23  Foundation                             0x189690914 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 212
24  CoreFoundation                         0x18879cc5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
25  CoreFoundation                         0x18879cba8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
26  CoreFoundation                         0x18879c894 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
27  CoreFoundation                         0x18879b208 __CFRunLoopRun + 820
28  CoreFoundation                         0x18879a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
29  idea                                   0x1046a49c4 main + 3332
30  dyld                                   0x1047f90f4 start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107687398 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 156
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654860 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 144
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654df0 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 252
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x107781454 Threads::destroy_vm() + 96
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x107489688 jni_DestroyJavaVM + 248
7   idea                                   0x1046a5b60 -[Launcher launch] + 896
8   Foundation                             0x1896682e8 __NSThread__start__ + 808
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: Java: GC Thread#0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x188695990 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libjvm.dylib                           0x1076f8094 OSXSemaphore::wait() + 24
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077e9f00 SemaphoreGangTaskDispatcher::worker_wait_for_task() + 24
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077e9894 GangWorker::loop() + 36
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: Java: G1 Main Marker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107687398 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 156
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654860 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 144
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654d74 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 128
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x1073897ac G1ConcurrentMarkThread::sleep_before_next_cycle() + 76
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x107389284 G1ConcurrentMarkThread::run_service() + 276
7   libjvm.dylib                           0x1072d1ec0 ConcurrentGCThread::run() + 56
8   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
9   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: Java: G1 Conc#0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x188695990 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libjvm.dylib                           0x1076f8094 OSXSemaphore::wait() + 24
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077e9f00 SemaphoreGangTaskDispatcher::worker_wait_for_task() + 24
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077e9894 GangWorker::loop() + 36
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:: Java: G1 Refine#0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107687398 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 156
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654860 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 144
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654d74 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 128
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x10738aae8 G1ConcurrentRefineThread::wait_for_completed_buffers() + 100
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x10738acb0 G1ConcurrentRefineThread::run_service() + 156
7   libjvm.dylib                           0x1072d1ec0 ConcurrentGCThread::run() + 56
8   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
9   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:: Java: G1 Young RemSet Sampling
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107685eb8 os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 228
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654850 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 128
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654d74 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 128
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x1073bc4b8 G1YoungRemSetSamplingThread::sleep_before_next_cycle() + 64
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x1073bc510 G1YoungRemSetSamplingThread::run_service() + 72
7   libjvm.dylib                           0x1072d1ec0 ConcurrentGCThread::run() + 56
8   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
9   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:: Java: VM Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107685eb8 os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 228
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654850 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 128
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654d74 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 128
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077cf240 VMThread::loop() + 316
6   libjvm.dylib                           0x1077ceffc VMThread::run() + 124
7   libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
8   libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 8:: Java: Reference Handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1886990c0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1808 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libjvm.dylib                           0x107687398 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 156
3   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654860 Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 144
4   libjvm.dylib                           0x107654e34 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 320
5   libjvm.dylib                           0x1074c0e68 JVM_WaitForReferencePendingList + 248
6   ???                                    0x10b313bfc ???
7   ???                                    0x11cd3bb98 ???
8   ???                                    0x10b308144 ???
9   libjvm.dylib                           0x10742bc20 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 732
10  libjvm.dylib                           0x10742af84 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Klass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 236
11  libjvm.dylib                           0x10742b04c JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, Klass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 100
12  libjvm.dylib                           0x1074bead8 thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 120
13  libjvm.dylib                           0x10777cd3c JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 128
14  libjvm.dylib                           0x10777cb68 JavaThread::run() + 296
15  libjvm.dylib                           0x10777a8d0 Thread::call_run() + 120
16  libjvm.dylib                           0x10767df34 thread_native_entry(Thread*) + 316
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886d1240 _pthread_start + 148
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1886cc024 thread_start + 8
```

With the error provided, can anyone point out the issue and how can I get rid of it?

PS: The error stack is too large, so I only provide the early lines of it.

Comment: This is probably beyond our ability to diagnose and resolve here. I would check JetBrains issue reports and see if you find anything that is acknowledged or has workarounds. You can find all issues tagged by M1Mac on their [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=tag:%20macM1). [JBR-4160](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4160) might have some helpful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That crash log indicates that Java chose to abort because it caught its code for moving or resizing windows trying to make use of a pointer variable that had not been set to point at whatever address it should have been pointing at. There was no way for the Java engine to know where that pointer was meant to point, so it chose to crash rather than risk screwing up worse.

It's hard for us to guess why the window-resizing code was trying to use a null pointer. It could be a bug in the window-drawing code, or it could be a bug in how IntelliJ called that code, or it could be something else.

Make sure you have the latest Java for M1 Macs, and the latest IntelliJ.

If this is not a widespread problem among people running IntelliJ on M1 Macs, then I guess you could try to see if it's something specific to your setup. For example, maybe you sometimes use IntelliJ with an external display connected, and leave some windows on that external display, and IntelliJ remembers those window locations, and then later you ran it without the external display connected, and when it tried to redraw those windows in their previous locations, it was unable to because that would be offscreen without the external display attached, so it somehow choked when trying to find a new place to put those windows that would be on-screen. Or, now that you know it has something to do with window moving or resizing, maybe you can figure out what you were doing that triggered it, and try to avoid doing that again. Like maybe it has buggy code when you try to maximize or un-maximize a window, so maybe you can find a way to live without doing that particular kind of window move/resize behavior.

I'm just grasping at straws at this point. This seems like a bug that someone at JetBrains will need to debug.

Comment: I use an Ultra-wide monitor from Xiaomi and maybe the issue is related to that. I like my monitor as it works perfectly and is so cheap. The issue happens only once in a few days so I guess I will just leave it as it is. Thanks for so elaborated answer.